# Failed connect to localhost:2633 ; Connection refused

Tags: connection, localhost

I have installed open-nebula and it's installed successfully.
But when i point to my IP. I can't access.
and when i checked log then it show this.

> Mon Feb  5 02:03:32 2018 [Z0][SCHED][E]: Cannot contact oned, will
>   retry... Error: HTTP POST to URL 'http://localhost:2633/RPC2' failed. 
>   libcurl failed even to execute the HTTP transaction, explaining: 
>   Failed connect to localhost:2633; Connection refused

Help in this ??